# PHP add different key value to array without array_merge

Tags: php, arrays

I have an settings array with some fixed values, but I need to be able to add an extra key value thats variable

```
$settings = ['height' => 10, 'width' => 20, 'fit' => 'crop'];

return new Settings(
    ['detail' => array_merge($options, ['foo' => 'bar']), 'detail-l' => array_merge($options, ['foo2' => 'bar2'])],
    ['small' => array_merge($options, ['foo3' => 'bar2'])],
);
```

But I don't think this is the best way, I would preferably not use array functions

My expected result would be 2 arrays that look like this

```
[
    'detail' => ['height' => 10, 'width' => 20, 'fit' => 'crop', 'foo' => 'bar'],
    'detail-l' => ['height' => 10, 'width' => 20, 'fit' => 'crop', 'foo2' => 'bar2']
]

[
    'small' => ['height' => 10, 'width' => 20, 'fit' => 'crop', 'foo3' => 'bar3']
]
```

Comment: Hi. Can you give us the expected result please?

Comment: I think `array_merge` is one of the best ways you're going to find. What is wrong with using it, if I may ask? Of course you could roll your own, but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Monnomcjo i added expected result

Comment: @RefugnicEternium it seems as if there is a more efficient way?

Comment: Like what? Regardless what approach you choose, you will have to make a copy of the array and add the new key to that, because otherwise you'd add the new property to all references to the array. And that's basically what 'array_merge' does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still believe that `array_merge` will do what you want with rather little overhead, here is a function you could use.

```
function pushToArray(array $data, string $key, $value)
{
    $data[$key] = $value;
    return $data;
}
```

It copies the array, adds the key/value combination and returns the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Use [splat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) operator:

```php
$settings = ['height' => 10, 'width' => 20, 'fit' => 'crop'];

return new Settings(
    ['detail' => ['foo' => 'bar', ...$settings], 'detail-l' => ['foo2' => 'bar2', ...$settings]],
    ['small' => ['foo3' => 'bar2', ...$settings]],
);
```